# Can i disable the "update account" activity in Journey Builder for certain users?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, user-management

I want to know if there is a way to grant/revoke permissions on the "update contact" activity of Journey Builder.
It can be quite problematic for it to be doable by any kind of user.

Thank you in advance.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only activities that are controllable through roles/permissions in Marketing Cloud are the Sales And Service Cloud activities. This does not include the Update Contact activity as this is a function of data extensions.

Here is a link to some journey activities permissions required for some of the activities: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_required_permissions.htm&type=5

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer !

Comment: @Kaouetar please remember to accept the best anwser by clicling on the check mark